# Update tables based on data from another one (LivePhoto table connect)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I'm trying to link my photos with video (live photos). I currently have two tables, one is for media and the other is for exif information.

Media table:

| id | type | visible | livephotoVideoId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | IMAGE | true | NULL |
| 23 | VIDEO | true | NULL |
| 24 | IMAGE | true | NULL |

Exif table:

| id | mediaId | imageName | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | IMG_0988 | ... |
| 2 | 23 | IMG_0988 | ... |
| 3 | 24 | IMG_0222 | ... |

There is only one couple (one image with same name as video) - no duplicate e.g. (One IMG_0988 IMAGE and one IMG_0988 VIDEO)

**What I need:**
update *livephotoVideoId* (media table) only if the name (IMAGE) is the same (VIDEO) and the type is (VIDEO) and then update (media table) visible column to FALSE for the video that was assigned to the image.

**Desired state**
Media table:

| id | type | visible | livephotoVideoId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | IMAGE | true | 23 |
| 23 | VIDEO | false | NULL |
| 24 | IMAGE | true | NULL |

Exif table:

| id | mediaId | imageName | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | IMG_0988 | ... |
| 2 | 23 | IMG_0988 | ... |
| 3 | 24 | IMG_0222 | ... |

I know the basics of SQL but sometimes I get lost in it and I seriously can't figure out how to do it in a way that doesn't ruin my DB. I also tried using group by select, row count... but in no case did I get a good result.

I tried something similar, but then I got lost and can't move anymore.

```
update media
set "livephotoVideoId" = (
        select e1.id from exif e1 left join media m2 on m2.id = e1."mediaId"
        where e1."imageName" = (
            select e2."imageName" from exif e2 left join media m3 on m3.id = e2."mediaId" where a3."type" = 'IMAGE'
        ) and a2."type" = 'VIDEO'
    );
```

Comment: Why have 2 tables?

Comment: The application is already built to use these two tables. I don't want to mix the EXIF data with the media, as the media contains information about the media such as where the original is saved, thumbnails, etc. These tables I sent are only simplified versions of those currently used by the application.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the desired output dataset without updating tables. It requires 3 queries using Access which should also work in postgreSQL. If there is a simpler approach in postgreSQL, you will have to figure that out.

Query1: VideoName

```
SELECT Media.ID, Media.type, Exif.ID, Exif.mediaID, Exif.imageName
FROM Media INNER JOIN Exif ON Media.ID = Exif.mediaID
WHERE (((Media.type)="Video"));
```

Query2: VideoImage

```
SELECT Exif.ID, Exif.mediaID, Exif.imageName, VideoName.Media.ID, VideoName.imageName, VideoName.type
FROM Media INNER JOIN (VideoName INNER JOIN Exif ON VideoName.imageName = Exif.imageName) ON Media.ID = Exif.mediaID
WHERE (((Media.type)="IMAGE"));
```

Query3:

```
SELECT Media.ID, Media.type, VideoImage.VideoName.Media.ID, 
    NOT Media.ID In (SELECT VideoName.Media.ID FROM VideoImage) AS TF
FROM VideoImage RIGHT JOIN Media ON VideoImage.mediaID = Media.ID;
```

If you really want to update table, use 3rd query as source for UPDATE action.